# Get Master Server Information from Slave instance

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

We need to get Master server information such as server IP and Port, we know this information is dumped into master.info file by default but what if it required within MySQL prompt as we are using windows enviorment and can not use system command too to read file from bash being in MySQL prompt and couldn't restart instance as well.

Is there any way of getting Master Server info from Slave server using some sort of dynamic select statements within MySQL prompt.

MySQL Version is 5.6.26 community  and  OS is Windows 2008R2

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `mysql` database.  You will see that some things that used to be files are now tables.  I think you are looking for `slave_master_info`.  It can be treated like a table for doing SELECTs.

Comment: Please let know from where and how to get those information as couldn't find related info from either variables or status commands within MySQL.

Comment: `USE mysql; SHOW TABLES; SHOW CREATE TABLE slave_master_info; SELECT * FROM slave_master_info;`  That info is not in `SHOW VARIABLES;` or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`